# GitHub invokes CI build after a pull request

Tags: github, circleci

**Background**

We are creating Pull-Requests on GitHub. After the PR is approved and the changes are successfully compiled and tested on CircleCI we push the button **Merge pull request**.

[image]

After pressing the button we would expect GitHub to immediately merge the PR but it first runs the very same build on CircleCI again and then it finishes the merge.

**Question**

How to merge a successful PR after pressing **Merge pull request** directly without running the CI build again?

If it's not possible then is there a way how to reduce some overhead?

For an unsuccessful PR, we want to prevent the merge though...

Comment: My **guess** is that it does that to make sure the build still passes after the merge, when two code bases (master and the branch) that have never been tested together ae merged. What happens when you rebase instead, or when you have a fast forward merge?

Comment: I think you are right.. Hm, do you think if there is a way how to tune up our PR process to reduce some overhead?

Comment: I prefer rebases from merges, but using rebases here wouldn't change much: the ci build would still have to be run after the rebase to make sure the code is still OK afer the rebase. I jus wouldn't see that as overhead, but as an insurance that everything is OK after the merge to master is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what's happening. When you merge a branch to your default branch (say master) on GitHub, GitHub does as expected, merges the code. The default branch will then have one or more new commits (depending on the type of merge you choose within GitHub).

Because CircleCI detects a branch with new commits, it then runs a build for that branch. This isn't initiated by GitHub, but CircleCI working as it always does. New commits means new build.

As JB Nizet commented, this is typically necessary because the tip of the feature branch isn't always tested with the latest code on master. Your CircleCI config for example can have branch specific instructions that only take place on `master`.

Personally, I wouldn't try to stop that last build from running. It's a safety check, which is exactly what CI is for in the first place. **If you really want to though**, when you first click the merge button, GitHub gives you a final chance to modify the merge commit's commit message and body. You can just add `[skip ci]` to the end of that commit message, and CircleCI will ignore the commit and not run a build.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We'll keep the build. ;)